# Route get current route {placeholder} value symfony

Tags: php, symfony, twig

is there a way to get the current route {placeholder} value in symfony?

I have :

```
/**
 * @Route("/ideas/{page}",
 * defaults={"page":1},
 * requirements={"page":"^\d+$"},
 * name="ideas")
 */
public function ideasAction($page) {

       .....

    return $this->render('idea/idea.html.twig', ["ideas" => $ideas]);

}
```

And in my twig I want to do something like this :

```
<a href="{{ path ('ideas',{'page': getCurrent + 1})}}" title="next page" class="btn btn-default"> > </a>
```

Is it possible?

Comment: You need to send the `placeholder` to the view, so that the view can access it. That's the only way other than storing the `placeholder` within the session, but that would be overkill. If you want to build a pagination, there are bundles for that.

Comment: Try this {{ app.request.get('page') + 1 }}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like Gara said :
With `{{ app.request.get('page') + 1 }}` you can get your placeholder

So this works :
`{% set page =  app.request.get('page') + 1   %}
  <a href="{{ path ('ideas',{'page':  page  })}}" title="next page" class="btn btn-default"> > </a>`